# external links not opening phonegap cordova android

Tags: android, xml, cordova, config

My Setup:
Mac Mini
Phonegap 5.0
Cordova 5.1
Platforms - iOS and Android
Android Studio

iOS app has no problem. But on android I'm unable to use internet through app i.e. unable to download any content from internet. I don't know if this is because an error in config.xml file or something else.

In my config.xml file which is found in res/xml folder, the contents are like

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    .......
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" /> </widget>
```

Error that I'm getting is

**Error:External resource http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets is not registered**

Can someone please me out here? Searching for a solution since 5 hours but unable to get any thing useful.

Whitelist plugin is also installed for android.

Comment: Are you added whitelist plugin in app ?

Comment: Hi Sanat, whitelist plugin is already installed for android

Comment: Any other errors in logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Re-installed the whitelist plugin.
Added **`<allow-navigation href="*" />`** in config.xml which was missing.
And voila! its working now. Thanks for your help [sanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024527/sanat-shukla)